Remove objects from array if they exist in another array
I am exploring JSONAta right now for fun and have a question on how to solve something.
I would like to remove objects from an array that exist in another array based on a match of the entire object (or if that's not possible, match on the Code attribute). For example:
$largerArray := [{"Name": "A", "Code": "100"} ,{"Name": "B", "Code": "200"},{"Name": "C", "Code": "300"}, {"Name": "D", "Code": "400"}];
$objectsToExclude := [{"Name": "A", "Code": "100"} ,{"Name": "B", "Code": "200"},{"Name": "C", "Code": "300"}];
$expectedArray := [{"Name": "D", "Code": "400"}];

So you can see only D is left in the array since A, B, C exist in both arrays.
Is there a way clean way to do this in JSONAta?
I was able to do simple exclusions such as the following:
$sourceArray := [1,2,3,4,5];
$removeArray := [3,4,5];

$result := $sourceArray[$not($ in $removeArray)];

My attempts at doing this with more complex objects is failing.

Given a JSON input such as:
[
  {
    "Name": "A",
    "Code": "100"
  },
  {
    "Name": "B",
    "Code": "200"
  },
  {
    "Name": "C",
    "Code": "300"
  },
  {
    "Name": "D",
    "Code": "400"
  }
]

To exclude objects based on the Code attribute, you can try:
(
  $objectsToExclude := [
    { "Name": "A", "Code": "100" },
    { "Name": "B", "Code": "200" },
    { "Name": "C", "Code": "300" }
  ];

  $expectedArray := $[$not(Code in $objectsToExclude.Code)];
)

Playground link: https://jsonatastudio.com/playground/2819d9c1
Comparing objects strictly (attribute by attribute) is possible but it won't be pretty or efficient. I'll have another think if you'd prefer that instead.

Thank you for your response!
Can you take a look at the playground link here and see why the dynamic exclusion is not working?
https://jsonatastudio.com/playground/2819d9c1

I am not sure what you mean. Please can you share your code here or in a different link?

Apologies - please see it here: https://stedi.link/GtgeJEt

Thanks for the link. I had a look and believe you are missing $$ in $[$not(itemCode in $$.item.removeSubItems.subItems.itemCode)] to reference the source JSON input. I've posted a separate answer.

Given a JSON input such as:
{
  "item": {
    "removeSubItems": [
      {
        "subItems": [
          {
            "name": "A",
            "itemCode": "100"
          },
          {
            "name": "B",
            "itemCode": "200"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "selectedSubItems": [
    {
      "subItems": [
        {
          "name": "A",
          "itemCode": "100"
        },
        {
          "name": "B",
          "itemCode": "200"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "subItems": [
        {
          "name": "C",
          "itemCode": "300"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

And a JSONata expression like:
$comboItems := {
  "ItemsToExclude": item.removeSubItems.subItems.itemCode,
  "ItemsWithExclusionsManualIsWorking": selectedSubItems.subItems.$[$not(itemCode in ["100", "200"])].{ "itemCode": itemCode }[],
  "ItemsWithExclusionsDynamicIsNotWorking": selectedSubItems
    .subItems
    .$[$not(itemCode in $$.item.removeSubItems.subItems.itemCode)]
    .{ "itemCode": itemCode }[]
}

The output should be:
{
  "ItemsToExclude": [
    "100",
    "200"
  ],
  "ItemsWithExclusionsManualIsWorking": [
    {
      "itemCode": "300"
    }
  ],
  "ItemsWithExclusionsDynamicIsNotWorking": [
    {
      "itemCode": "300"
    }
  ]
}

Playground link: https://jsonatastudio.com/playground/c469b093
